# Arch linux sound doesn't work

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio

both firefox and vlc play silence through built in speakers. pavucontrol said that vlc is playing correctly through hdmi but when switched pavucontrol says that it stops playing. and pavucontrol doesnt even recognize that amarok is playing sound when it is working perfectly. sound cards:

```
lspci -nn | grep Audio

00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio 
Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High 
Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the built-in sound kept setting itself to headphones. `pavucontrol` fixed it perfectly.

Comment: yea sound + GNU/Linux is still sometimes a hell. Definitely when using a secondary sound card (like I have), since there is no sound card built-in the motherboard... 

Now again, with the latest update I also don't have sound again.. `pavucontrol` is no option too bad. Running Linux kernel 4.7.6-1-ARCH. I'm out of luck :( In fact, digital output is often easier (correctly) recognized v.s. analog output, don't ask me why.